# Laravel Auth::attempt() fails, laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel

the Laravel Auth::attempt function fails always. But i can't find any other method to authenticate the user or the false code...
I checked the Input from my Form with an echo in the following if condition ( else part, because the true condition never entered).

```
public function postSignIn(Request $request)
{
    $email=$request['email'];
    $password=$request['password'];
    $remember=$request['remember'];

   if(Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])){
        return redirect()->route('dashboardStart');
   }
        return redirect()->back();

}
```

The password is hashed by the normal laravel hash function and saved to the database.

```
$pw=Hash::make($pw1);
```

to store pw and email

```
   $user->Email=$email;
    $user->Password=$pw;
   //writes the data to the DB
    $user->save();
```

So, hope someone can help me.

EDIT 2:

Ok that's crazy... 
I changed the validation function and validate the email and password with the normal php function and the condition is true...

```
if(($email===$userDBEntry['Email'])&&password_verify($password,   $userDBEntry['Password'])){
        return redirect()->route('dashboardStart');
   }
        return redirect()->back();
```

Comment: What problem you are facing?

Comment: Please post the exact error message you are getting

Comment: I don't get any error message. Only Auth:attempt returns allways false

Answer (score 0):

i think you are not taking inputs correctly request is not an array it's a function so call function to get input

```
public function postSignIn(Request $request)
{
   if(Auth::attempt( $request->only(['email','password']) ){
        return redirect()->route('dashboardStart');
   }
        return redirect()->back();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you check what you get for `$password` and `$email`
I agree with Sam, you should use methods of the Request object to access the attributes, such as

```
$email= $request->input('email');
$password= $request->input('password');
```

more about it in [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/requests#retrieving-input).

EDIT: 2 more ideas on what to try...
verify that you do have that user in the database (if it is not there, then there is a problem somewhere with saving/registration process)

try changing

```
$pw=Hash::make($pw1);
$user->Email=$email;
$user->Password=$pw;
```

to

```
$user->email=$email;
$user->password=$pw1;
```

And also verify that you are getting the $email and $pw (or $pw1) values as you expect them to be.

Comment: can you do: 
{{dump($request['email'])}}
{{dump($request['password'])}}
 and
{{dump($request->input('email'))}}
{{dump($request->input('password'))}}

Comment: the dump looks good. "test@test.de"
"test"
"test@test.de"
"test"

Comment: then my next suspect would be it might be "double hashed" or some other similar problem with password hashing. How do you store password when the user is created?

Comment: I've added how i store the pw and email to my question

Comment: sometimes you are using capital Email and sometimes email as attribute name. what is the column name in db and what is the attribute name defined on your user model?

Comment: the DB Column and Modell is Email. the 'email' is the id and name of the field in the HTML form

Comment: did you check if pass is "double hashed". I used the default Auth implementation from laravel and the $user->save() method automatically hashes the password, making your line $pw=Hash::make($pw1); hashing the input, and then on save method hashing it again.
If also that does not help, i would go testing using the check() method
if (Hash::check('plain-text', $hashedPassword)) {
    // The passwords match...
}

Comment: ok, so i have removed the code to hash the password. Now the Password is stored in plaintext in the DB. The ->save function don't hashed the PW automatically. The hash function is now bcrypt($pw), and i can check for correct pw with  password_verify($password,   $userDBEntry['Password']).

Comment: with every iteration of our comments i think of another thing to check. are you by chance using a field "verified" or "confirmed" and that is 0 when you register the user? or any other checks you might be doing in the Auth::attempt() method check the source code of that and see why it returns false

Comment: i have some confirmation fields for the password and email validation by laravel. And i have a rememberd field... is there any chance to see what happens in the auth::attempt process?

Comment: i dont use the build in logincontroller to log in a user. Is this maybe a problem, because i'am using a UserControler with a model to login a user ?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `Illuminate\Http\Request` and putting it in the function, `postSignIn(Request $request)`.

The correct way to retrieve email/password from the Request object is to call `$request->email` instead of `$request['email']` when you pass it to the `Auth::attempt`.

---

So:

`$email=$request['email']; // make it $request->email
$password=$request['password']; // make it $request->password
$remember=$request['remember'];`